# Why doesn't this javascript execute?

Tags: jquery, jinja2

I'm trying to get a bit of jquery to work inside a jinja2 template.  The expected behavior is that checking the SelectAll box will check the rest of the boxes.  I've added an alert to the .change event to start debugging, and I've found that it's not run.  So the script is never actually called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block head %}<head>
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(':checkbox[name=selectAll]').change (function () {
    $(':checkbox[name=instances]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    alert("FOO");
});
</script>
</head>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<form target="" method="GET" id="testform">
<div>
Select All: <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAllInstances" /> <br />
    {% for k in tests %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="instances" value="{{ k[1].mongo_id }}">{{ k[0] }} <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Description: {{ k[1].__doc__ }} <br />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: document.ready function :)  you should read through this to help you learn the basics http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time this line executes:

```
$(':checkbox[name=selectAll]').change(...);
```

There is no checkbox named selectAll -- it is defined below the script. Wrap your code inside the .ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

The event fires when the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed (in simple words, when the browser has seen `</html>`).

Answer (score 3):

The template is a red herring. Your checkboxes don't exist at the time the script that binds the event handlers to them runs.

You have a few options.

- Move the script element to a point in the HTML after the checkboxes
- Wrap the script in a function and delay calling it until later (e.g. with a document.ready event).
- Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of direct binding.

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap you jquery in document.ready i.e.

```
$(function(){
   $(':checkbox[name=selectAll]').change (function () {
    $(':checkbox[name=instances]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    alert("FOO");
   });
});
```

without it the script runs before the DOM elements are ready to be traversed

NOTE:

```
$(function(){...code here ...});
```

is shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
});
```